# Accessing data from json in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON object Like this-

```
[
{
    "user": "A220",
    "shorttext": "shanghai",
    "reportedBy": "S,A",
    "questions": "

[{\"question\":\"Q1\",\"is_mand\":\"0\",\"type\":\"text\",\"answer\":\"w\",\"ansYesOrNo\":false,\"ansDetails\":\"\"},{\"question\":\"Q2\",\"is_mand\":\"0\",\"type\":\"text\",\"answer\":\"ed\",\"ansYesOrNo\":false,\"ansDetails\":\"\"}]",
        "notifno": "20143995",
        "error": "",
        "createdOn": "2015-09-09 13:08:36",
        "Id": 0,
        "$$hashKey": "object:89"
    }
]
```

I need to access the 1st **question** of **questions**.Please i am not able to access it like this alert(obj.questions[0].question);
Here is a jsFiddle Link-[LINK to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhul/w02ck9uw/)

Comment: It is in an array, use `obj[0].questions[0].question` after you fix you questions array - remove backslashes. Use [this site](http://jsonlint.com/) for your json validation.

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w02ck9uw/2/  use JSON.parse

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a text representation of a JavaScript object. What you have is a JS object with whats seems to be a JSON string as the value for the `questions` property, which seems very messed up. Usually it's full on one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the questions array inside the object, It is not an array. Is a Array convert to string, you must parse the questions to get the respective Json object with the data.

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/marduke182/w02ck9uw/1/

And the part of code important:

```
var questonObj = JSON.parse($scope.a[0].questions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) method this way:

```
angular.fromJson(a[0].questions)[0].question
```